# Adding non-numeric values to a histogram in SAS or R

Tags: r, sas, histogram

Please note: I can use either SAS or R to achieve my desired results. If you don't know how to use SAS, I provide the data and info for R further down the post.

Here's a simple sample dataset created in SAS, which shows the conditions I am facing:

```
data df;
format x best12.;
do i=1 to 30;
    x=.M;
    output;
end;
do i=1 to 200;
    x=.;
    output;
end;
do i=1 to 1000;
    y=ranuni(1)*1000+1;
    x=put(y,8.4);
    output;
end;
keep x;
run;
```

As you can see, there are missing values of '.' and of '.M'. If I make a histogram, all of these values seem to be thrown out for the histogram. However, their existence is visible in a report.

```
ods listing;
proc univariate data=Df;
   var x;
   histogram;
run;
ods listing close;
```

When running this `proc univariate` I have several pages of reports and then the histogram. The relevant info is found as shown in these images:
[image]
[image]

The desired result is to include these missing values on the histogram image. In my actual usage, I will be preparing histograms for more than 200 variables, and having all required information on a single image for each variable would be much more useful than having to scroll through hundreds of pages of reports.

Here is an example of my desired result. However I would settle for having the missing percentages listed as text somewhere in the image if adding them directly to the histogram bars is not possible.
[image]

Is there a way to do this in SAS? The extra bars should actually affect this histogram percentages, so if 80% of the values are missing then it will be visible as a bar way bigger than the others with numbers.

If not, perhaps it is possible in R. Exporting my data to R is relatively trivial. So assume the same data is offered here:

```
structure(list(x = structure(c("M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "185.9626", "971.0887", "400.8243", "260.3986", 
"922.6026", "970.2773", "543.9792", "532.6917", "50.794", "67.5666", 
"820.3186", "524.8705", "854.3943", "68.1846", "958.0239", "298.194", 
"273.6118", "690.9296", "977.7649", "227.5075", "689.2366", "413.7639", 
"559.5541", "288.2256", "476.7893", "845.987", "635.5241", "591.3647", 
"583.5815", "378.0134", "729.3616", "507.6035", "932.2136", "930.12", 
"590.6603", "298.2228", "392.0424", "473.4292", "680.5257", "169.0884", 
"167.5261", "872.1049", "299.7895", "935.6418", "901.4708", "569.7835", 
"50.5457", "136.5883", "512.3179", "434.2046", "177.1058", "666.036", 
"405.8187", "125.5488", "454.4868", "200.5531", "575.8372", "739.474", 
"440.8122", "50.367", "523.3822", "344.3653", "23.7123", "713.8879", 
"938.0646", "446.9931", "947.9372", "713.8987", "104.2727", "176.172", 
"269.9059", "615.8565", "421.7076", "72.7371", "359.4938", "712.4349", 
"190.8499", "148.9664", "562.8355", "271.1087", "326.1991", "570.1784", 
"43.5944", "440.2106", "918.4351", "526.8418", "732.816", "906.2236", 
"577.0038", "188.9431", "332.326", "699.8738", "122.5631", "181.6658", 
"271.6393", "654.2119", "422.3725", "38.9777", "271.8063", "428.7339", 
"821.1031", "844.4531", "877.9101", "268.22", "307.0246", "398.0483", 
"350.0518", "766.9348", "544.4015", "613.5734", "553.913", "736.9083", 
"372.8579", "646.6469", "558.1772", "876.0427", "572.2385", "757.7711", 
"149.4293", "26.437", "818.2168", "659.2194", "30.4726", "854.3927", 
"363.8533", "378.3175", "511.5414", "712.9408", "376.3303", "230.5369", 
"687.2141", "553.4322", "582.8184", "175.7225", "47.0957", "644.7989", 
"646.4478", "94.1665", "621.0778", "79.4527", "690.2577", "185.02", 
"621.4688", "194.4664", "296.323", "632.003", "385.8154", "687.4354", 
"492.9653", "830.9891", "45.3908", "204.4657", "79.9962", "146.1177", 
"225.4361", "348.5495", "703.1268", "492.4519", "632.3485", "907.3614", 
"305.0696", "926.8537", "441.649", "609.3854", "782.9232", "427.3273", 
"126.2918", "741.4407", "195.8032", "817.7258", "86.4755", "184.7618", 
"333.636", "706.581", "928.611", "297.4189", "225.0418", "148.189", 
"591.641", "464.2575", "419.599", "257.3096", "231.4521", "81.3435", 
"436.5923", "671.1953", "423.7238", "499.2745", "856.4391", "601.0225", 
"513.2634", "596.8914", "45.0338", "517.9692", "689.8435", "454.3286", 
"836.6544", "298.4456", "404.2475", "957.8356", "422.9367", "781.7931", 
"332.0596", "173.1015", "911.5578", "269.9737", "957.0176", "138.199", 
"272.9045", "557.9157", "659.248", "685.6502", "15.3484", "768.6924", 
"609.2854", "538.7332", "21.1416", "645.6661", "965.0621", "181.5664", 
"602.0622", "973.7504", "352.1731", "153.7375", "666.7509", "63.3307", 
"582.9058", "707.2334", "425.7658", "53.6991", "486.482", "939.8279", 
"644.7048", "536.67", "635.2019", "308.0852", "222.2622", "558.3752", 
"607.3624", "602.1178", "36.9078", "799.3215", "386.7776", "782.2929", 
"271.7681", "203.2705", "755.7987", "452.5837", "373.1987", "405.6169", 
"779.4035", "304.9959", "906.9386", "308.2276", "621.2043", "755.556", 
"504.0589", "429.6581", "767.2686", "991.1561", "572.7591", "801.0568", 
"512.9949", "201.699", "947.3559", "811.6579", "291.8313", "312.0987", 
"519.8151", "800.8539", "516.8318", "958.9357", "476.1095", "949.7048", 
"640.9645", "484.0937", "651.5747", "520.2282", "234.8962", "900.3894", 
"693.1371", "427.9634", "147.0431", "226.1329", "199.6782", "773.3236", 
"991.8145", "351.7495", "454.3664", "283.0351", "70.4709", "541.2402", 
"199.2659", "41.8104", "686.3233", "924.3151", "438.8517", "240.3994", 
"209.1992", "57.8957", "471.0023", "676.4539", "669.0446", "813.0324", 
"188.8539", "912.9967", "946.0608", "357.5811", "645.5963", "752.5301", 
"229.098", "946.4856", "443.8694", "653.635", "861.5289", "654.633", 
"547.9526", "217.6461", "385.6536", "702.7005", "288.3574", "276.5411", 
"948.4602", "702.3759", "787.7155", "860.4903", "809.5756", "214.9675", 
"888.5069", "977.8302", "724.182", "640.4782", "755.1235", "159.4327", 
"210.0291", "552.827", "972.9385", "568.8218", "182.943", "199.0987", 
"739.394", "957.0497", "399.1318", "287.5669", "228.5352", "763.5288", 
"362.8183", "15.7433", "421.8691", "10.7537", "168.9205", "576.1645", 
"941.8231", "414.2527", "964.6047", "823.6905", "29.808", "731.8761", 
"453.8193", "338.6814", "979.1373", "982.4637", "493.9553", "404.8051", 
"953.978", "680.9686", "6.0802", "10.6348", "178.2355", "640.8735", 
"988.9237", "94.2299", "455.3864", "995.2248", "795.0074", "697.7844", 
"180.0715", "760.4194", "178.7672", "364.7651", "622.3498", "71.2859", 
"915.1567", "841.2615", "938.6384", "642.8329", "109.7501", "11.212", 
"791.8081", "228.004", "608.2395", "647.5117", "244.3697", "857.0005", 
"457.1681", "46.0384", "166.0815", "63.19", "235.6531", "974.1699", 
"126.7906", "444.7151", "9.7581", "430.7482", "791.3288", "157.1319", 
"87.8969", "499.7956", "654.765", "27.4485", "124.4274", "4.3653", 
"974.2801", "84.3725", "290.0972", "210.3595", "766.8113", "476.8953", 
"893.7874", "352.6818", "212.391", "485.9383", "123.0042", "821.0203", 
"875.4745", "852.0494", "510.9897", "742.9106", "419.6393", "605.3322", 
"495.4695", "463.7911", "990.863", "356.8746", "412.0952", "97.3777", 
"803.3194", "460.8084", "108.5638", "55.5635", "566.3803", "412.8094", 
"814.7781", "118.7314", "994.6653", "295.9439", "969.3008", "469.6288", 
"145.148", "702.3593", "461.5773", "779.0193", "670.6038", "284.8408", 
"659.042", "810.1945", "118.3677", "274.2438", "295.2056", "993.7999", 
"973.448", "902.9239", "413.2769", "379.2431", "680.7533", "394.9922", 
"945.6788", "624.722", "406.4948", "465.636", "230.8293", "510.3886", 
"728.458", "443.88", "194.1945", "54.8419", "267.4354", "340.8108", 
"66.5481", "165.8289", "72.0559", "500.3151", "302.1719", "609.7822", 
"318.0166", "505.3297", "790.9808", "496.3614", "914.392", "408.3293", 
"629.7713", "987.2263", "342.2658", "116.7494", "999.7048", "473.2114", 
"379.8607", "270.948", "131.3105", "317.3986", "89.4428", "475.1982", 
"62.21", "340.5318", "724.8074", "89.0325", "724.8313", "813.228", 
"767.4524", "597.1436", "327.7372", "476.632", "733.4944", "538.8605", 
"557.6343", "818.9034", "553.3628", "789.9897", "16.913", "425.8398", 
"727.8405", "19.1406", "830.4988", "638.3202", "949.3691", "280.7647", 
"635.6984", "515.8156", "439.0264", "837.2173", "995.6913", "916.9842", 
"192.3891", "791.1708", "936.1215", "127.3613", "131.1873", "457.531", 
"504.508", "545.5348", "158.1025", "145.0966", "742.9074", "269.6511", 
"390.9124", "492.4721", "180.8201", "112.5", "670.2907", "94.9885", 
"681.6701", "556.6188", "942.8924", "91.1424", "925.7007", "390.9405", 
"684.2877", "611.2362", "336.2536", "690.5464", "805.3683", "270.2932", 
"273.9049", "189.531", "542.1381", "32.4074", "910.9336", "118.0686", 
"388.5666", "646.223", "655.7028", "990.4283", "682.1596", "967.8979", 
"503.9537", "615.232", "808.0248", "57.3946", "399.9911", "508.6546", 
"735.0188", "336.7563", "438.7867", "864.155", "628.043", "577.7379", 
"796.0536", "820.6869", "322.1132", "639.6276", "292.0172", "658.6991", 
"918.1194", "257.8712", "275.6201", "42.5074", "949.5604", "696.918", 
"54.2326", "952.3529", "282.2365", "350.4344", "158.6643", "924.6886", 
"60.4696", "890.7313", "82.1267", "121.1292", "565.9524", "516.4049", 
"494.4737", "782.6651", "823.7738", "75.6671", "299.9372", "808.6502", 
"730.0349", "643.716", "334.6902", "277.428", "994.2802", "939.4066", 
"562.6745", "185.8866", "784.9558", "131.809", "134.8747", "247.8866", 
"978.3516", "695.5582", "530.7795", "239.7878", "333.9312", "693.1315", 
"998.9222", "518.1969", "142.8932", "964.7987", "305.4655", "138.3047", 
"538.6714", "632.4899", "364.6074", "76.6572", "391.1019", "607.2232", 
"347.1533", "246.5421", "700.8786", "845.9716", "813.5647", "937.0058", 
"994.8333", "508.4189", "802.4961", "689.9831", "353.0825", "694.6961", 
"603.4495", "542.9621", "611.002", "932.0611", "810.3", "972.0262", 
"646.4119", "884.5466", "392.2544", "823.1692", "426.8816", "607.1", 
"938.4085", "558.9458", "776.486", "159.9047", "970.0521", "876.7853", 
"886.0768", "223.7484", "987.9194", "106.3544", "288.8817", "321.134", 
"619.9767", "475.6006", "918.0446", "401.5002", "904.1853", "646.4752", 
"944.4168", "756.6958", "930.5543", "48.6663", "341.664", "965.2013", 
"296.7024", "533.8722", "649.5287", "355.4043", "9.1982", "38.2914", 
"316.0813", "418.5179", "780.7503", "696.0666", "798.3291", "150.4867", 
"729.2404", "675.4917", "689.9732", "662.3665", "420.2621", "755.2172", 
"344.2887", "709.5542", "983.5345", "33.0365", "226.9772", "344.7762", 
"422.4038", "663.4982", "92.0537", "44.7676", "947.6471", "650.9532", 
"279.0353", "424.3423", "402.5659", "133.1801", "35.2343", "282.782", 
"64.1469", "623.3967", "690.6633", "284.0618", "469.2275", "991.9513", 
"828.4532", "472.1298", "658.0149", "471.4351", "634.7074", "809.3303", 
"327.1528", "323.698", "152.0059", "21.5413", "712.5852", "703.8751", 
"175.2252", "651.1252", "781.6538", "657.5007", "698.0728", "661.9578", 
"616.3443", "782.7727", "344.3334", "116.2572", "500.237", "166.4211", 
"496.9333", "192.2514", "47.98", "664.1206", "497.4444", "271.2836", 
"336.6008", "233.7287", "849.0963", "278.1842", "121.9383", "423.5104", 
"655.7927", "14.5324", "308.7161", "50.1885", "412.4437", "992.889", 
"800.3944", "186.7711", "487.0814", "245.414", "407.8053", "786.8064", 
"642.9563", "635.8652", "610.5934", "33.4489", "90.8328", "526.5662", 
"237.364", "96.3168", "568.4725", "724.7312", "982.5129", "129.329", 
"179.7677", "167.8462", "685.4671", "577.9849", "953.633", "316.0254", 
"713.1554", "549.5741", "970.0241", "709.0122", "686.0794", "818.9696", 
"952.6099", "862.8962", "18.3049", "962.0972", "950.6321", "646.8501", 
"622.1503", "395.1015", "892.3881", "702.5592", "378.5131", "432.9628", 
"648.5462", "194.7267", "135.2709", "160.1734", "760.7965", "428.7074", 
"924.5702", "749.6376", "868.7443", "564.2507", "376.4343", "441.5547", 
"839.3707", "117.1167", "7.1011", "306.6166", "3.397", "839.7049", 
"105.3713", "195.6873", "396.5144", "941.2713", "502.8532", "909.3083", 
"415.5281", "676.3949", "246.785", "841.9609", "850.8536", "770.0396", 
"605.022", "193.8714", "297.5457", "626.0234", "877.8313", "365.2988", 
"407.11", "543.7302", "121.795", "764.0918", "11.979", "67.6425", 
"18.4728", "409.0951", "389.4057", "735.3737", "183.4104", "805.6381", 
"954.6486", "790.5828", "22.5228", "760.1009", "971.9821", "460.9531", 
"401.5527", "653.4836", "790.2295", "932.82", "66.7457", "680.4396", 
"701.1791", "759.1867", "587.2498", "170.6856", "711.3639", "650.1843", 
"43.1462", "458.4786", "905.54", "240.3128", "604.3034", "31.3091", 
"541.1093", "757.7448", "591.293", "659.1233", "754.5859", "368.8301", 
"796.6814", "373.8775", "176.7159", "552.9335", "410.3892", "41.615", 
"814.5713", "733.1952", "971.9638", "929.6915", "98.5514", "371.08", 
"487.3651", "674.5217", "709.6539", "961.4552", "402.9765", "218.9928", 
"662.4137", "140.6063", "357.3221", "955.983", "784.804", "558.1331", 
"487.5895", "696.3418", "4.9448", "868.3812", "260.5816", "820.0505", 
"839.5843", "708.0438", "820.6154", "116.5226", "124.4367", "255.7617", 
"748.5931", "570.4943", "263.0048", "261.9168", "313.8063", "60.3583", 
"728.2438", "233.206", "543.423", "857.3499", "533.4335", "707.2373", 
"567.0104", "329.2016", "390.2727", "978.6919", "12.2579", "902.5805", 
"645.8404", "194.7968", "268.1894", "439.1287", "924.3094", "883.4786", 
"542.8591", "943.1775", "401.9489", "686.0916", "833.7638", "644.0075", 
"885.367", "390.6116", "395.6609", "502.7026", "426.2273", "318.2967", 
"728.6603", "217.3236", "228.5971", "301.0794", "768.3377", "75.51", 
"494.3128", "226.8128", "787.7257", "187.4007", "60.4328", "351.4584", 
"64.7187", "18.5175", "133.1031", "752.4957", "656.1083", "130.069", 
"8.4988", "368.194", "885.7056", "709.7175", "571.7867", "153.7275", 
"34.6657", "690.2913", "951.7159", "346.8914", "128.868", "85.2696"
), format.sas = "BEST")), label = "DF                              ", row.names = c(NA, 
-1230L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Using `hist(as.numeric(df$x))` I get a histogram with the 'M' values changed to NA. I think these plus the NA values are thrown out when making the histogram.
[image]

Is there a way in R to make the histogram but include bars for the NA and M values? I know I could "count" them and put them as annotations, but if I am going through the trouble of exporting my data to R then I would expect to be able to visualize it as bars of the histogram.

In my real dataset, I have the following details:

```
                                    The CONTENTS Procedure

    Data Set Name        INLIB.PRODUCTION                     Observations           119081
    Member Type          DATA                                 Variables              223
    Engine               V9                                   Indexes                0
    Created              02/14/2015 19:27:29                  Observation Length     1790
    Last Modified        02/14/2015 19:27:29                  Deleted Observations   0
    Protection                                                Compressed             CHAR
    Data Set Type                                             Reuse Space            NO
    Label                                                     Point to Observations  YES
    Data Representation  WINDOWS_32                           Sorted                 NO
    Encoding             wlatin2  Central Europe (Windows)


                               Engine/Host Dependent Information

Data Set Page Size          16384
Number of Data Set Pages    7759
Number of Data Set Repairs  0
Filename                    --\data\production.sas7bdat
Release Created             9.0202M3
Host Created                W32_VSPRO
Owner Name                  --
File Size                   121MB
File Size (bytes)           127124480
```

And some variable names:

```
                          Alphabetic List of Variables and Attributes

  # Variable           Type Len Label

209 act12_n_arrears    Num    8 Customer number in arrears on all
                                loans during the last 12 months
210 act12_n_arrears_   Num    8 Customer number of days greter than 15
    days                        on all loans during the last 12 months
211 act12_n_good_days  Num    8 Customer number of days lower than 15
                                on all loans during the last 12 months
 92 act3_n_arrears     Num    8 Customer number in arrears on all
                                loans during the last 3 months
 93 act3_n_arrears_    Num    8 Customer number of days greter than 15
    days                        on all loans during the last 3 months
 94 act3_n_good_days   Num    8 Customer number of days lower than 15
                                on all loans during the last 3 months
131 act6_n_arrears     Num    8 Customer number in arrears on all
                                loans during the last 6 months
132 act6_n_arrears_    Num    8 Customer number of days greter than 15
    days                        on all loans during the last 6 months
133 act6_n_good_days   Num    8 Customer number of days lower than 15
                                on all loans during the last 6 months
```

Comment: You can edit `hist()` objects directly. If you do `output <- hist(...)` you will see that it is just a list with various bits of info. It will be a bit fiddly to set up but you could change the breaks/mids/counts parts of the object and then `plot(output)` to add in extra values. Either that or you could revert to just using a `barplot` after `cut`-ing the data into chunks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SGPANEL` can create output for each variable but will require some data manipulation to get the data columns needed for statements such as `PANELBY` and `INSET`.  A histogram chart ignores missing values, and computes the histographic bins based on the distribution.  Adding 'dummy replacement values' for missing values so they end up in the historgram will mess up the distribution -- so don't go that route.  A useful approach is to have a small freq table in the output listing the missing values and their counts.

Sample data:

The generated sample data has 1,000 records and 200 metrics (I call them *facts*)

```
data have;
  do observationId = 1 to 1000;
    array fact fact1-fact200;
    do _n_ = 1 to dim(fact);

      fact[_n_] = round(_n_ * 100 + rannor(123),0.01);

      if ranuni(123) < 0.015 then fact[_n_] = .;
      else
      if ranuni(123) < 0.015 then fact[_n_] = .M;
    end;
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Sample code:

The code requires several steps in order to transform the data into a shape (and content) suitable for `Proc SGPANEL`

- `Transpose` by row so the 200 variables can be processed with a `BY` statement
- Assign `varOrder` to maintain column ordering of original data set during `BY` processing
- Use `PUT` to compute the output representation of the missing values
- Sort by the assigned `varOrder` so each by group contains the values of the corresponding original column
- Use `FREQ` to count the number of each missing value representation within each group
- Transpose the freq output into a 'wide' layout with each count variable having the same name prefix, so that name list syntax : can be used later.
- Merge the missing counts with the original data.  You might notice the repetition of the counts within the group, but that is the layout `SGPANEL` needs for `INSET`
- Perform the `SGPANEL` step generating the graphs

Code

```
* pivot data into categorical form for by processing;
proc transpose data=have out=haveByFact(rename=col1=fact);
  by observationId;
  var fact:;
run;

* track ordering and missing representation;
data haveByFact2;
  set haveByFact;
  by observationId;
  if first.observationId then varOrder=1; else varOrder+1;

  if missing(fact) then missingRender = put(fact, best12.);
run;

* sort for by group processing;
proc sort data=haveByFact2 out=haveByFact3;
  by varOrder;
run;

* count missings;
proc freq noprint data=haveByFact3;
  by varOrder _name_;
  table missingRender / out=missFreq(keep=VarOrder missingRender Count) ;
  where missing(fact);
run;

* arrange missings counts for merging and later INSET use;
proc transpose data=missFreq prefix=missingv_ out=missFreqT(keep=varOrder missingv_:);
  by varOrder;
  id missingRender;
  idlabel missingRender;
  var count; 
run;

* merge missings counts with original data;
data haveByFact4;
  merge haveByFact3(drop=missingRender) missFreqT;
  by varOrder;
run;

* SGPANEL Ho! ;

options nobyline;
proc sgpanel data=haveByFact4;
  by varorder _name_;
  title "Distribution of response #BYVAL2";

  panelby _name_
  / noheader
    proportional
    uniscale=row
  ;

  histogram fact 
  / scale = count
  ;

  colaxis display=(nolabel);

  inset missingV_: / title="Missing Freq";

  where varOrder in (8,9,10);
run;
```

Sample output

[image: Histograms of each column]

Comment: My columns aren't named by fact1-fact200, and if I rename them then I will no longer know which variables are which.

Comment: The name `Fact*` is simply for convenience of sample data, they can be anything. In the first transpose change `fact:` to a list of your variables, or `_NUMERIC_` to transpose all numeric variables. After transposition the original variable names become data in the column `_NAME_`  If you have a mix of numeric and character data, they numeric would be histogramed and you would have do more coding for doing character variables as `VBAR`

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/WlHLV9B.png Example of my column names. No coherent pattern. When I tried to use your code on my dataset I already have had problems. `158  proc transpose data=Production out=haveByFact(rename=col1=fact);
159    by cid;
160    var fact:;
WARNING: No variables found beginning with 'FACT' in data set WORK.PRODUCTION.
161  run;

NOTE: No variables to transpose.
NOTE: There were 119081 observations read from the data set WORK.PRODUCTION.
NOTE: The data set WORK.HAVEBYFACT has 0 observations and 14 variables.`

Comment: I edited as you suggested, and am now trying to run it. But it inflated the rows to 25 million observations, so I had to change my graphics maxobs, and we will see how many minutes (or hours) it takes to run.

Comment: Well after half an hour my computer ran out of hard drive space. Your method generated more than 30GB of temporary data.

Comment: Can you add the `PROC CONTENTS` output for your data set? If the transpose has 25M rows I would guess the original data set had ~125,000 rows if you have 200 vars. The errors from your log show 119,081 rows. I would not expect 30GB file size unless there were some long character variables that carried along into the fray.  Try the process for a single numeric and see how that goes.  You can macroize the code to run for smaller sets of variables at a time (instead of all at once)

Comment: Ok, I added. Yes, the variable names are super long and there are labels that are sometimes 30+ characters

Answer (score 2):

The `SGPLOT` `VBAR` statement has a `MISSING` option that will cause missing values to be a valid category and show a bar for them.  Unfortunately when the category data contains multiple versions of missing (your `.` and `.M`), the bar is *stacked* and not *discrete*. One remedy is to use a custom format and data view to pre-render the missing values into the desired category values.

Sample code:

```
data have;
  question = '1A';
  do response = ., .M, 1 to 10;
    do _n_ = 1 to 25 * ranuni(123);
      surveyID + 1;
      output;
    end;
  end;
run;

ods graphics / width=320px;
proc sgplot data=have;
  vbar response / missing;
run;
```

Remedy

- Custom format
- Data view

The format definition `. = "A0"x'.'` is using an atypical string construct for defining the missing value representation.  The A0 hex character is a non-breaking space and will collate after 7-bit ASCII characters.

```
proc format;
  value missSep
   . = "A0"x'.'
   .M = "A0"x'.M'
  ;
run;

data vbarData / view=vbarData;
  set have;
  responseX = put(response,missSep.);
run;

proc sgplot data=vbarData;
  vbar responseX;
run;
```

[image: SGPLOT VBAR]

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I'm looking for. Only problem is, I'm not sure how to make charts for all 200 variables without doing it one by one, or using a macro loop. Univariate lets me specify the data and just call histogram to get a chart for each variable. Is there a way to do this with sgplot/vbar?

Comment: Oh no, this approach doesn't work because it is counting every unique value. `WARNING: BARCHARTPARM statement will not be drawn because the DISCRETEMAX threshold has been
         reached. You can set DISCRETEMAX=12,200 on the ODS GRAPHICS statement to draw the
         plot.`

Comment: A lot depends on the data structure. Use a `BY` <category-id> statement if your data is categorical response (each category can be thought of as a separate variable).  Is your response data points non-categorical multi-variate ?

Comment: Look at the sample data I generated for this question. There are more than 1,000 unique results. This is similar to my actual situation. I have a dataset with more than 200 variables, and I don't currently know much about these variables. The histograms can give me a quick view of the behavior of each variable, but it disregards the missing values. In one variable that I've tested, 86% of the values are missing (35% '.' And 51% '.M')

Comment: I should also point out that the variables are not survey responses. The dataset is about financial accounts in a wide form, with each row having a unique account id. My ultimate goal is to understand how each variable (column) behaves.

Comment: Perhaps there's a way to make the histogram aND use it as the bars which are then combined with missing values in sgplot? I would need a way to automate this process on all variables.

Answer (score 1):

I did some changes in the code, basically created another variable 'y' for subgrouping, see code below -

```
data Miss1 Rest;
length y $15.;
 set df;
if x=. then 
do;
    y='Missing(.)';
    output Miss1;
end;
else 
do;
    y='Other';
    output Rest;
end;
run;

data Rest1;
length y $15.;
 set rest;
 if missing(x) then 
 do;
    y='Missing(.M)';
 end;
run;

data df_new;
 set Miss1 Rest1;
run;

proc gchart data=df_new; 
vbar x/missing levels=all type=PCT subgroup=y; 
run; 
quit;
```

I am getting following chart now, hope it helps[image: ![Gchart]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GK9Ar.png)

```
/*Using Discrete option and macro for footnote*/
%macro gchart(var);
proc gchart data=test; 
footnote &var;  
vbar &var/missing levels=all type=PCT discrete; /*or hbar &var/missing levels=all type=PCT discrete;*/
run; 
quit;
%mend gchart;

%gchart(x);
```

Comment: This is almost what I need and in a simple way. If there's a method to show the split between '.' and '.M' (even just text on the chart) then I would go for this answer for it's simplicity.

Comment: I believe SAS treats both the values(. and .M) as missing, so it does not differentiate between them .. this article mentions about the sort order of missing values: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000989180.htm

Comment: I tried to put your code into a macro in order to run it on all 223 of my variables, but unfortunately I did something wrong and crashed SAS, deleting all of my progress. Perhaps I'll give it another shot in the morning.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/kdu1Obe.png Look at this example output for one variable. Is there a way to rotate the x axis marks and extend them to 5 or 6 digits? And is there a way to show the variable name and label? (not just label)

Comment: You can use other options for horizontal bar (hbar) instead of vbar. And if your dataset has few data points then go with Discrete option in vbar/hbar statement. look at my modified answer. Also, if you want to show both varname and label, I would use a footnote statement using variable name passed as an argument in a macro. see example in my code.